# How to Return in Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I dont really understand i have written return in the end  but still it gives error

CODE :

```
int factorial(int num)
{
    int N;
    if (num > 1) 
    {
        N =  (num * factorial(num--));
    }

     else 
        return N;
}

int main()
{
    cout << factorial(5);
    return 0;
}
```

ERROR : warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
16 | }

Comment: double (and more) UB, you either don't return or return uninitialized value.

Comment: You're not returning anything if `num > 1`, and `N` is uninitialized if the condition is false. Also, the value of `num--` is its value before decrementing, and `num * factorial(num--)` has undefined behaviour since `num` and `num--` are not sequenced.

Comment: Remove else, move return inside if and `return 1` outside if

Comment: `return num <= 1 ? 1 : (num * factorial(num - 1));`.

Comment: You may want to also have the code throw an exception if num is greater than 20 if you are using a 64 bit int or greater than 12 if you are using a 32 bit int.

Comment: The most important step towards understanding recursive functions is realizing that they work exactly like non-recursive functions. Suppose you had `int f(int num) { int N; if (num > 1) N = num; else return N; }`. What would it return?

Comment: "I don't understand" is a rather difficult/broad _question_ to answer.  Perhaps you can edit this question to explain what you think `factorial(1)` will return?  If you're confident in what `factorial(1)` returns, perhaps you can step through `factorial(2)` and see how that call never reaches a `return`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you don't return anything. If you look at the flow of the program you can see that for `num > 1` you do the factorial stuff and for `num <= 1` you just `return N`. For `num > 1` the return statement is never reached. This issue can be fixed by removing the `else`, BUT that leaves an other issue mentioned, namely that for `num <= 1` `N` is never initialised. If you initialise it to `1` that should solve that, but as people pointed out you don't need `N`, you can do `return num * factorial(num - 1);` and simply `return 1` for `num <= 1`. The final problem with your code is that you do `num * factorial(num--)`. `factorial(num--)` will call `factorial(num)`, when you would need `factorial(num-1)`, because `num--` is the post-decrement operator.

Other suggestions in the comments are good to heed as well, like implementing guards from integer overflow and the like.